# UserStatusUpdateMessage JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to send a status update-message when an admin goes online, idle, .... offline. My Code is working but there is a bug.
The bot will send update-messages for all users on the server .. i just want to get status updates of admins ..

This is my code:

```
public class LoginMessageListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onUserUpdateOnlineStatus(UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent event) {
        OnlineStatus os = event.getGuild().getMember(event.getUser()).getOnlineStatus();

        if (event.getGuild().getRoleById("628650613152153640") != null) {
            TextChannel channel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("628645905955815454");

            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
            builder.setThumbnail("http://i.epvpimg.com/t43Pfab.gif");
            builder.setFooter("Powered by Backxtar.");
            builder.setTimestamp(OffsetDateTime.now());
            builder.setColor(0xf22613);
            builder.setDescription("Admin **" + event.getUser().getAsMention() + "** is now **" + os + "**!\nI'm __always available__ for questions,\nsuggestions or problems!\n:point_right: [**Da Hood - Join NOW!**](https://discord.gg/xyz) :point_left:");

            channel.sendMessage(builder.build()).complete().delete().queueAfter(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } 

        else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check with `if (event.getGuild().getRoleById("628650613152153640") != null)` only checks if the role exists in the server. To check if the user has the role you have to check the roles with `event.getMember()`:

```java
private static boolean isAdmin(Member member) {
    return member.getRoles().stream()
        .mapToLong(Role::getIdLong) // we check by id
        .anyMatch(id -> id == 628650613152153640L); // true if any role has that id
}

@Override
public void onUserUpdateOnlineStatus(UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent event) {
        OnlineStatus os = event.getGuild().getMember(event.getUser()).getOnlineStatus();

        if (isAdmin(event.getMember())) {
            // code
        }
// the else here is unnecessary
}
```